# Data not binding to Select on first Ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**EDIT:**
One unusual thing that i notice is that if i select an option from parent SELECT (which fires AJAX call to bring data for binding the next SELECT ) , if i immediately try to open it it continues to show no options but if I wait for couple of seconds , I am able to see the options !

I am trying AngularJS for first time and facing a problem wherein the SELECT control is not binding on FIRST Ajax call but displays item when AJAX call is done second time. The AJAX is fired on change event of another drop down

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.singleSelect = ' ';

    $scope.IsVisible = false;

    $scope.GetValue = function () {

        $scope.IsVisible = true;
        $scope.DefaultLabel = "Loading.....";



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../ContentPages/frmManualAccess.aspx/BindDelegationLevel",
            data: "{pDelegationLevel :'ALL'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (msg) {

                console.log(JSON.parse(msg.d));

/* Gives array of 3 objects 
[{"DelegationCode":"Customer","DelegationName":"Customer"},
 {"DelegationCode":"Segment","DelegationName":"Segment"},
 {"DelegationCode":"SBUM","DelegationName":"Customer"}]
*/
                $scope.myOptions = JSON.parse(msg.d); 
                $scope.defaultDelegationLevel = $scope.myOptions[0].DelegationCode;
            },

            error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {

                var varResponseText = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

                alert(varResponseText.Message);
            }
        });


    }

});
```

And in HTML the SELECT i am trying to bind is below

```
<select ng-model="defaultDelegationLevel" 
   ng-options="option.DelegationName as option.DelegationCode for option in myOptions" >
</select>
```

I dont know why its happening , please help in this issue. Also an empty option appears as first option that i am trying to remove.

Comment: See if you can remove "option.DelegationName as" from ng-options. And change defaultdelegationlevel into the following: "$scope.defaultDelegationLevel = $scope.myOptions[0]" without ".DelegateCode"

Comment: FYI, AngularJS has it's own way of doing AJAX calls. If you inject $HTTP, you would then have a promises based way of handling the response. Right now it sure appears that you're using jQuery to handle that call.  - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @Chris Thanks for pointing me in correct direction , using $http helped in overcoming the issue. ` $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "../ContentPages/frmManualAccess.aspx/BindDelegationLevel",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { pDelegationLevel: 'ALL' },
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`